# Understanding boundary conditions for spherically symmetric dielectrics in Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, boundary-conditions, dielectric

I'm looking for some help understanding the reading in Classical Electrodynamics, JD Jackson, Chapter 4.4, Boundary-Value Problems.

They state the potential as equations 4.48 and 4.49 as the separable solutions to the Laplace equation for a spherically symmetric system, shown below.

MY QUESTION IS TWO-PART: What are the physics theories behind equations 4.50?  AND: How did the author know to look for relations in the tangential & normal directions, and why  not in the azimuthal?

What I tried:

For the Normal part I tried deriving eqn. 4.50 with Gauss's law in differential form, but it resulted in a Laplacian operator not a partial derivative.

For the Tangential part, it looks like the gradient of potential, but that is not one of Maxwell's equations.  So, I'm not sure how to proceed.

For the azimuthal part: this is omitted because its solution in the separation of variables is just 1.  So, maybe that's why we don't consider it when working through boundary conditions.

Thanks so much for any guidance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's law will not help because E is not radially symmetric.
Read the section on Legendre polynomial expansion again.
Equation 4.48 and 4.49 are the standard expansion equations.
Equation 4.50 for D is from the continuity of D_normal at the interface.
The equation for E_tangential is more complicated than necessary.
It is simple to equate 4.48 to 4.49 at r=a, using comtinuity of he potential.